# Split moments of inertia into vectors - Right thing to do?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, moment-of-inertia, inertia

Let's say that we have the moment of intertia:

$$J = mR^2$$

And the mass $m$ is on the $(x, y)$ position. Can I say that moment of intertia is then:

$$J = mR^2 = m\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} ^2 = m(x^2 + y^2)$$

The same if I got two masses $m_1, m_2$ and $m_1$ is on position $(x_1, y_1)$ and mass $m_2$ is on the position $(x_2, y_2)$. The moments of intertia are then:

$$J = m_1R_1^2 + m_2R_2^2 = m_1\sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2} ^2 + m_2\sqrt{x_2^2 + y_2^2} ^2  = m_1(x_1^2 + y_1^2) + m_2(x_2^2 + y_2^2)$$

Is this true? Or is it true, but it's a very bad way to do that formulation. Especially if the masses $m_1 , m_2$ are on a robotic arm.

Comment: Moment of inertia is a second rank tensor, not a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is what you already have with $R^2$, the implication being that it involves a central axis.

If you do what you are doing, your moment of inertia would involve this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I find out that $sin^2(\theta) + cos^2(\theta) = 1 \forall \theta$

Comment: And the equation $e^{i\theta} = Cos (\theta) +i Sin (\theta) $ will also occupy a large part of your life in the future. Thanks for asking the question, it's years since I looked at inertia. Regards

Answer (score 1):

### By component

You can add the components of two mass moment of inertia *tensors* if they are expressed on the same point, and on the same orientation.

So when resolved on the origin each mass $m_i$, located at $\pmatrix{x_i & y_i}$, contributes to the total mass moment of inertia, a $m_i (x_i^2+y_i^2)$ amount.

The total MMOI is

$$ I_{zz} = \sum_i m_i (x_i^2+y_i^2) $$

### As a tensor

A a 3×3 tensor each mass $m_i$, located at $\pmatrix{x_i & y_i}$, contributes the following amount

$$ {\rm I} = \sum_i m_i \left[ \matrix{
  y_i^2+z_i^2 & -x_i y_i & -x_i z_i \\ 
  -x_i y_i & x_i^2+z^2 & -y_i z_i \\
  -x_i z_i & -y_i z_i & x_i^2+y_i^2
} \right] $$